# Playwright fail to authenticate using storage state. Firebase token

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I am setting up Playwright framework from the scratch and trying to reuse authentification with the help of storage state and I faced an issue when my tests fail trying to authentificate.

1. There is a setup file with login, retrieving and preserving the storage state.

[image]

2. There is a config file with test, trying to navigate to e.g. '/home' page, but instead it's stuck at '/login', obviously not having a proper authentification.
[image]

I did setup storage state passing with `test.use()` and globally in the `playwright.config.ts` file with the `starageState` key.
What could be wrong here? Am i missing something important?

My auth spec looks like this:

```
    const loginPage = new LoginPage(page);

    await loginPage.goto();
    await loginPage.login({
        email: ENV.EMAIL,
        password: ENV.PASSWORD
    });

    await expect(page).toHaveURL('/home')

    await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');

    console.log(await page.context().storageState());

    await page.context().storageState({ path: STORAGE_STATE });
```

And the test basically nothing more than navigation to '/home' and validating the URL.
I was thinking maybe I am missing something in regard of cookies.
Important note: We use Firebase token for authorization, maybe this storage stage is just not enough to login?

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Without the site I'm not sure how to help here. Can you share a [mcve] please? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you for a reply. Updated the description with code examples.